# Override Wordpress CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

I have wordpress site with some layout.

I need to change some css there, but got troubles overriding it.

Via webbrowser my CSS looks like:
[image]

It is places (genetated?) somewhere in theme.

Every time I refresh page I got different '**class-xyz**' (on the screen it is: class-GkgfbCohxE) name in **#inbound-list**

I have added to custom CSS below (changed color):
[image]

But this is not loaded.

All structure of this CSS:

[image]

Do you know how to enable ovverriding this element?

Comment: A **bad** way could be to use `!important` here: `color: #861111 !important;` [It's all about Specificity!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: what if I want to override whole css style for this element (with new css attributes)?

Comment: You only need to be a bit more specifc. As I don’t know your DOM you could try `body #inbound-list > li:before {}`. I recommend you to learn about Specificity!

Comment: Thanks! It is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the theme and plugin you use.

For my experience, this dynamic inline CSS may come from the page builder you use. If it comes from page builder, please check your page builder and adjust the style.

If you want to overwrite the css, you could simply put `!important` after the color attributes.

Answer (score 0):

To override this css you need to use any parent id like below or you can apply some id to your body tag and write ur css with its reference

see my ex below

```css
#parent #one li{
  color: blue;
}
#one.asd li{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <ul id="one" class="asd">
    <li>aaa</li>
    <li>bb</li>
    <li>adfdf</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a your theme styles, you can create a child-theme, then overwrite the styles. You can also use the same selector in the child-theme css, WordPress knows that it has to take the ones from the child-theme.